# Dual SIM sound, vibration and notification settings

Tags: notifications, vibration, dual-sim, silent-mode

I have a Huawei P20 Pro. This might be a quirk with their software, but I thought I should ask either way.

Let's say you have two phones with two numbers. One is your private phone and one is your work phone. During the day you can put your private phone on silent and your work phone with sound on. When you go home for the day you can put the work phone on silent and turn the sound on for your private phone.

If you put both SIM-cards in the P20 Pro, you cannot choose to have one SIM with sound on, and one on silent. You can choose that one SIM should vibrate and one should not. This only works with sound on. If you put the phone on vibrate, it vibrates for both SIM-cards. If you put it on silent, it is silent for both sim cards.

I also have the problem that I can set the notification sounds to "None", but I can't seem to turn off the vibration for notifications. I want the notifications for all apps in the notification bar, but I do not want sound or vibration no matter the settings for calls. So to sum up, this is what I was hoping to be possible. Is there an app for this?

- Individually control sound, silent mode, and vibration on/off for both SIM-cards
- Turn off sound and vibration for all notifications from apps like Facebook, Messenger, Instagram, SMS Messages, etc. regardless of silent mode, vibration mode or sound volume, etc.

Is one of these or both of these possible, with or without an app? I may root the phone if I can keep the stock firmware, it is safe, and possible to reset.

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting / sound and notification / General / phone ringtone. Select second sim card / select ring tone. Now you need to add ringtone with no sound. You can modify existing ring tone to no sound.

You need to root mobile. There is ringtone and ringtone_2.

You can find under media/ internal / audio / media / here are the list of ringtone. Change it to silent ring tone.

This is the only way. There is no setting to silent one sim card on android.

Comment: As far as I know you don't need to root the phone.  Otherwise it is a valid solution, so +1